# 1985 Xr 250 Lots of play in shifter?

Tags: transmission

I am thinking about buying a 1985 Xr 250 but i am very concerned about the amount of play there is with the shifter lever , is this due to the clutch cable is broke ? or is there any other issue i need to look at or will getting a new clutch cable and adjusting it up properly solve the very sloppy play in the foot shifter lever . I can feel the gears but there is way to much play .

Answer (score 1):

The play in the clutch cable is separate to the play in the shifter mechanism.

You will have to check and correct both.

Why do you say the clutch cable is broken? If it is it needs replacing, if not then adjusting.